# Integrating WAAD on existing Webform asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, azure-active-directory

I am looking for step by step guide on converting an existing Web Forms asp.net application to use Windows Azure Active Directory authentication (WAAD).

We can assume we dont have to convert/migrate users to the Azure AD.

FYI: I dont have any problem creating a blank WebApplication using VS2013 to connect to WAAD, however I am not clear why changes are needed in existing Webform / MVC hybrid application.

Thanks

Comment: I'm working on the same thing.  Did you ever find any help on this?

Comment: see suggested solution below

Answer (score 1):

I created a blank project using the steps outlined http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/20/ws-federation-in-microsoft-owin-componentsa-quick-start/

move/copied the web.config sections from the blank project

```html
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://login.windows.net/myorganizationdomain.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
    <add key="ida:Realm" value="https://mywebsite.com/myproject" />
    <add key="ida:AudienceUri" value="https://localhost:44318/" />
  </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-myproject.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-myproject;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" requestValidationMode="4.5" />
  </system.web>

<system.identityModel>
  <identityConfiguration>
    <issuerNameRegistry type="myproject.Utils.DatabaseIssuerNameRegistry, myProject" />
    <audienceUris>
      <add value="https://mywebsite.com/myproject" />
    </audienceUris>
    <securityTokenHandlers>
      <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </securityTokenHandlers>
    <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
  </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
<system.identityModel.services>
  <federationConfiguration>
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://login.windows.net/myorganizationdomain.com/wsfed" realm="https://mywebsite.com/myproject" requireHttps="true" reply="https://localhost:44318/" persistentCookiesOnPassiveRedirects="true" />
  </federationConfiguration>
</system.identityModel.services>
```

- copy the generated code DatabaseIssuerNameRegistry.cs from Utils
  folder,  from the "blank" project into the existing project.
- copy theTenantRegistrationModels.cs and TenantDbContext.cs from the "blank"
  project into existing project
- copy the IdentityConfig.cs from the "blank" project into existing project

In the Global.asx.cs add the following

```
IdentityConfig.ConfigureIdentity();
```